# google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotator exceeded 600000 milliseconds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, aiml

It was working well for a year and we have not changed anything. I think something has changed recently in cloud vision. I am getting this error on Production Server no way to know what is wrong. On Production Server I am able to do telnet on vision service.

telnet vision.googleapis.com 443 gives the expected output.

Version:

```
"@google-cloud/vision": "^2.1.1"
```

```
May 09 13:46:43 fi-services npm[20346]: GoogleError: Total timeout of API google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotator exceeded 600000 milliseconds before any response was received.
May 09 13:46:43 fi-services npm[20346]: at repeat (/opt/******/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:66:31)
May 09 13:46:43 fi-services npm[20346]: at Timeout._onTimeout (/opt/*****/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:101:25)
May 09 13:46:43 fi-services npm[20346]: at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
May 09 13:46:43 fi-services npm[20346]: at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
May 09 13:46:43 fi-services npm[20346]: code: 4
May 09 13:46:43 fi-services npm[20346]: } error
```

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest to contact Google support for this as engineers has a better visibility on your logs and resources for this matter.  https://cloud.google.com/contact